# Blender shows error when I save my project once I add in a texture

Tags: materials, error

In recent days, I've been running into a problem where once I add in textures to objects in my scene and try to update my save, I get this error:

```
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
```

File "/Users/sperosoaps/Library/Application Support/Blender/3.0/scripts/addons/poliigon-material-converter/poliigon_ui.py", line 90, in draw
addon_updater_ops.check_for_update_background()
File "/Users/sperosoaps/Library/Application Support/Blender/3.0/scripts/addons/poliigon-material-converter/addon_updater_ops.py", line 727, in check_for_update_background
updater.set_check_interval(enable=settings.auto_check_update,
File "/Users/sperosoaps/Library/Application Support/Blender/3.0/scripts/addons/poliigon-material-converter/addon_updater.py", line 511, in set_check_interval
raise ValueError("Enable must be a boolean value")
ValueError: Enable must be a boolean value

location: :-1

**Why is Blender giving me this error?**

Answer (score 1):

That appears to be a problem with Poliigon's [Material Converter Script](https://help.poliigon.com/en/articles/2540839-poliigon-material-converter-addon-for-blender).

There are (at least) two releases of the script.  Make sure that you have Version 3.1.3 installed.  Earlier versions do not work with 3.0 alpha.

If you have the latest version, then you need to contact Poliigon at <support@poliigon.com>.